# MouseLeftButtonDown on column header of a GridControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, devexpress, gridcontrol

I'd like to simulate MouseLeftButtonDown event on the ColumnHeader of my GridCotrol. I'd like to make that my app "thinks" that I've pressed header of its column.

How can I do this?

What have I done so far? Well, a lot of things that didn't work.

I really need help on this one.

My plan is to simulate that event after MyGrid is loaded and all data is loaded.

```
 private void MyGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
              //data gets loaded

              //magic happens
              //...
            }
```

Comment: What is the final task you are trying to accomplish via pressing Grid column header? Because I believe there is "normal" way to enable the same functionality...

Comment: I'm having a problem with grouping. Can't group rows on the runtime. It gets grouped only if I click on column header. Sounds strange, I know, but I really can't figure it out why is it behaving like that. For this reason I need to simulate that click on column header.

Comment: Have you reported the issue with grouping to DevExpress team? From my experience their developers can implement a hot-fix or  suggest you with a temporary workaround quite fast

Comment: No, I haven't since that grouping is working in different and not for my current project. Workaround for me would be to simulate that column header click. But either way, thanks for that thought.